# AdWords API get costs

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am looking for a simple solution to extract daily costs from Google AdWords via the API. I've looked at [Apility](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-apility/) and the official AdWords API, but the first is not maintained any more while the second is an overkill - I mean 76MB of uncompressed code to only get the daily costs?

Does anybody know of a simple solution to get the costs from Google AdWords?

Comment: Presumably you won't need to compile all in all of that 76MB, and it'll compile down to something much smaller anyway?

Comment: Ithink I should have specified that I am looking for a PHP solution, so there is nothing really to compile

Comment: @AdrienHingert, did you find any to extract daily costs from Google AdWords via the API, i am facing same problem not any suitable solution get it, please post if you find any solution

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to API costs, there's the GetUnits call, used in the [AdWords API Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/tutorial.html).

If you're referring to running campaign costs, you can use a [StatsSelector](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/AdGroupCriterionService.StatsSelector.html). You will want the cost/microAmount.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
composer require googleads/googleads-php-lib
```

Script for Laravel 5.8

Google Ads v201809

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands\Google;

use App\Model\AdvExpense;
use App\Model\Campaign;
use App\Model\Source;
use App\Service\Xml;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\DownloadFormat;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\ReportDefinition;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\ReportDefinitionDateRangeType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\Reporting\v201809\ReportDownloader;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\DateRange;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\SortOrder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Expenses extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'google:expenses';
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'Import Google Ads Expenses';
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = "Import Google Ads Expenses";

    public function handle()
    {
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile(storage_path('adsapi_php.ini'))->build();
        $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())->fromFile(storage_path('adsapi_php.ini'))->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)->build();

        $date = Carbon::yesterday();

        $this->saveExpenses($session, $date);
    }

    public function saveExpenses($session, $date)
    {
// Create selector.
        $selector = new Selector();
        $selector->setFields(['CampaignId', 'CampaignName', 'Clicks', 'Cost']);
        $selector->setDateRange(new DateRange(
            $date->format('Ymd'),
            $date->format('Ymd')
        ));

// Create report definition.
        $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
        $reportDefinition->setSelector($selector);
        $reportDefinition->setReportName('Expenses report ' . uniqid());
        $reportDefinition->setDateRangeType(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::CUSTOM_DATE);
        $reportDefinition->setReportType(ReportDefinitionReportType::CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);
        $reportDefinition->setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat::XML);

// Download report.
        $reportDownloader = new ReportDownloader($session);
        $reportDownloadResult = $reportDownloader->downloadReport($reportDefinition);
        $result = $reportDownloadResult->getAsString();

        $report = Xml::namespacedXMLToArray($result);
        foreach ($report['table']['row'] as $item) {
            $campaign_id = $item['@attributes']['campaignID'];
            $campaign_name = $item['@attributes']['campaign'];
            $cost = $item['@attributes']['cost'];

            if ($cost > 0) {
                $dbCampaign = Campaign::where('code', $campaign_id)->get()->first();

                if ($dbCampaign) {
                    $price = round($cost / 1000000);
                    if ($price) {
                        $dbCost = AdvExpense::updateOrCreate(
                            [
                                'campaign_id' => $dbCampaign->id,
                                'date' => $date,
                            ],
                            [
                                'price' => $price,
                            ]
                        );

                        if ($dbCost->exists) {
                            $this->info($dbCampaign->name . ' - ' . $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' - ' . $price . ' OK');
                        } else {
                            $this->error($dbCampaign->name . ' - ' . $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' - ' . $price . ' ERROR');
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->error('Campaign ' . $campaign_name . ' not found!');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use APILity as the API version it supports was depreciated several years ago. The project was halted in favour of the new official PHP AdWords API Library. Some functions of it still work (such as the AdWords Reporting Service) but that won't last for too long now.

I would recommend using the official library if possible because it makes development and upgrading so much simpler but if you really need a lighter footprint you can try constructing the API calls yourself using the standard PHP Soap extension.

Comment: thanks ewan, the fact is that the official api looks like an overkill for what i need to do. do you know of any tutorials on how to strip it down to the bare minimum?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a tutorial on this? I wrote some code to do it a while back but it was harder than expected and I can't find it now :P

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend AdWords Scripts, https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/. Write Javascript directly in AdWords UI, handles basic stuff pretty well.